# How to erase what is written by "document.write()"

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on writing small game that is written in javascript, alot like "snake".  Part of it is that me showing grid and that grid needs to be updated often.

And one way for me to do that is using below function.

```
function loadImages(){

    for(var i = 0;i<HEIGHT;i++){
        for(var j = 0;j<WIDTH;j++){
            if(grid[i][j] == -1){
                document.write('<IMG SRC="wall.png" width="30">');
            }
            else if(grid[i][j] == 0){
                document.write('<IMG SRC="empty.png" width="30">');
            }
        }
    }

    setTimeout( loadImages(), 50 );
}
```

Only problem is that when loadImages() function is called over and over, images are concatenated not, replacing.

So my questions is that is there a way to overwrite document, or clear?

P.S. "document.clear()" function doesn't seems to be all that helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Use jQuery. And for a game, have a look at HTML5's canvas element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend your `grid` data structure and store both the state and the image element:

```
// initialization
for(var i = 0;i<HEIGHT;i++) {
    for(var j = 0;j<WIDTH;j++){
        grid[i][j] = {
            state: grid[i][j],
            image: new Image()   // creates HTMLImageElement object
        };
        // set width
        grid[i][j].image.setAttribute("width", "30");
        // append HTMLImageElement to BODY element
        document.body.appendChild(grid[i][j].image);
    }
}
```

Then you can change the images inside `loadImages` in a similar manner:

```
function loadImages() {
    for(var i = 0;i<HEIGHT;i++){
        for(var j = 0;j<WIDTH;j++){
            if(grid[i][j].state == -1){
                grid[i][j].image.src = "wall.png";
            }
            else if(grid[i][j].state == 0){
                grid[i][j].image.src = "empty.png";
            }
        }
    }
    setTimeout(loadImages, 50);
}
```

By the way: `setTimeout(loadImages(), 50)` calls `loadImages` immediately but you should pass the function instead, so `setTimeout(loadImages, 50)`.

You can optimize this your `loadImages` function by storing `grid[i][j]` in a temporary variable and only change the images’ source if the state has changed:

```
var cell = grid[i][j];
switch (cell.state) {
case -1:
    if (cell.image.src !== "wall.png") {
        cell.image.src = "wall.png";
    }
    break;
case 0:
    if (cell.image.src !== "empty.png") {
        cell.image.src = "empty.png";
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: I really like this approach, but how do I display image with "image()" object??  i'm so noob at js...

Comment: @Ankiov Spetsnaz: This solution uses DOM operations. In this case `new Image()` creates a new *HTMLImageElement* object (the same that `<img>` does in code) and you can change the image’s source with the `src` property of that *HTMLImageElement* object. In this case the first call of your `loadImages` function will initially set the `src` property for the images. Maybe you should add a test whether the `src` assignment is necessary at all (i.e. only initially and when the state changes).

Comment: hm... I'm still looking at the blank page and I think I have everything right...  How do I display this to a document? Also, I don't think document.body.appendChild is working for me...

Comment: @Ankiov Spetsnaz: `document.body` is only available when the `BODY` element already has been found in the document. So put this code at the end of `BODY` or call it when the document has been loaded.

Comment: I feel incompetent to keep asking, but this is what I did.  I put initialize code in "initailizeGrid()" function and added "<body onload="initializeGrid()">" and inside that tage I call "loadImages()"  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

document.write is always additive; you're always adding a new element(s) to the document object (DOM).

What you want, in this case, is document.getElementById('imgParent').innerHTML, with the child(ren) image(s) being within the element with ID.

```
document.getElementById('imgParent').innerHTML = '<IMG SRC="wall.png" width="30">';
```

Really, though, consider a library like jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing would be to not use `document.write`, but to instead write to a particular document element.  For example, start with the following document:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body><div id='game'></div></body>
</html>
```

Then instead of "document.write", do:

```
var game = document.getElementById('game');
game.innerHTML = '<IMG SRC="wall.png" width="30">';
```

You could set the game.innerHTML property frequently, and it will overwrite.

Comment: but then how do you display actual pictures?  I understand that it load into the "div id='game'" but I'm unclear on how to display what is loaded.

Comment: @Ankiov - This will *actually create* an `<img>` element inside the div, as if it were there in the original HTML document.  The browser will take care of rendering the picture, just as it would with any other `<img>` tags it encounters (such as the one you're currently `document.write()`-ing).